# Report on Account --> Parent Account --> Opportunities

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, joined-reports, report-chart

I am new to Reports. I am trying to create a report with Opportunities.
I need to get Account with record type 'ABC' and then go to this parent account(one lookup field is there on Account) then get all the opportunities with record type = 'XYZ'.

Account(Record Type "ABC") --> Parent Account --> Opportunities(Record type "XYZ")

I need count of opportunities, Summarize with Account , Total Revenue those kind of reports.

Please let me know if its possible or not. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried by creating the custom report type to pull the accounts with Opportunities.

Comment: Yes @ShirishaPathuri but i am not able to filter opportunities for Parent Account only. And also not able to add filter on Opportunity record type ="XYZ". Can joint report will be helpful?